# Should I be stripping colons from strings before creating a tsquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

We are using websearch_to_tsquery() in our app. I've noticed that when passed a "quoted" string to find an exact match, it will interpret a colon character ":" as a word, while to_tsvector does not. This prevents a tsquery from matching a tsvector created from the same string. The behavior exists in at least Postgres 12 and 13. Is this expected?

With a colon:

```
SELECT websearch_to_tsquery('english', '"Design Patterns in C++: Behavioral - Observer to Visitor"')
'design' <-> 'pattern' <2> 'c' <2> 'behavior' <-> 'observ' <2> 'visitor'
```

Now with the colon removed:

```
SELECT websearch_to_tsquery('english', '"Design Patterns in C++ Behavioral - Observer to Visitor"')
'design' <-> 'pattern' <2> 'c' <-> 'behavior' <-> 'observ' <2> 'visitor'
```

Note the `'c' <2> 'behavior'` vs `'c' <-> 'behavior'`. A tsvector created from the same string with a colon does not include a colon as a word. That is what I would expect, but this means the tsquery will not match a tsvector created from the same string.

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', '"Design Patterns in C++: Behavioral - Observer to Visitor"')
'behavior':5 'c':4 'design':1 'observ':6 'pattern':2 'visitor':8
```

Documentation for [websearch_to_tsquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html):

> Converts text to a tsquery, normalizing words according to the specified or default configuration. Quoted word sequences are converted to phrase tests. The word “or” is understood as producing an OR operator, and a dash produces a NOT operator; **other punctuation is ignored**. This approximates the behavior of some common web search tools.

*Should I be stripping colons from strings before creating a tsquery? Are there other characters that characters that need to be removed?*

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug that will be fixed in v14, but the change was deemed to invasive to backpatch into older releases, because it depends on some other changes which were not getting backpatched.

https://postgr.es/m/16592-70b110ff9731c07d@postgresql.org
https://postgr.es/m/CAPpHfdv0EzVhf6CWfB1_TTZqXV_2Sn-jSY3zSd7ePH%3D-%2B1V2DQ%40mail.gmail.com